# Angular 6 + get elements with class name from document and change style

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, angular6

I have a set of "tabs" in my HTML page. They are nothing but "div" with a class name "tab". My intention is to show one tab at a time and use "Next" and "Previous" buttons to access other tabs. HTML code looks like this.

```
<div class="container">
  <div *ngFor="let question of questionList;let i = index" class="questionBox tab">


    {{question.question.query}}

    <br>
    <div *ngFor="let option of question.options">
      <input type="radio" value="{{option.id}}" name="radio_{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="question.selected.id">{{option.text}}
      <br>
    </div>
    {{question.selected | json}}

    <br>
    <br>
    <!--TO DO -->
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Previous">
    <!--TO DO -->
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary nxtButton" value="Next">
  </div>
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block" value="Submit">
</div>
```

Initially all the tabs are hidden with CSS.

```
.tab{
    display: none; 
}
```

on page initialization, first tab has to be displayed and rest are hidden.
**showTab()** method in the component class is intended for that purpose. shotTab method accepts a "number" that represents the index of the tab to be displayed.

```
  public showTab(n: number){

    let tabElements = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
    let tabToDisplay = tabElements.item(n) as HTMLElement;
    tabToDisplay.style.display="block";
  }
```

to show the first tab, showTab() methos is invoked from **ngOnInit()** method of the component. but the line **let tabElements = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");** does not return any result. i.e. the length of **tabElements** is 0. So the application will fail saying that "**Cannot read property 'style' of null**".

```
AppComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at AppComponent.push../src/app/app.component.ts.AppComponent.showTab (app.component.ts:25)
    at AppComponent.push../src/app/app.component.ts.AppComponent.ngOnInit (app.component.ts:18)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:9243)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:10507)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:10469)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:11102)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:11062)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (AppComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:11054)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10451)
```

Comment: Call `showTab()` in `ngAfterViewInit()` instead of `ngOnInit()`. The difference is that it's run after the children have been initialized.

Comment: thanks... that worked. please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `showTab()` in `ngOnInit()` means it's called before the children have been initialized.

You need to use `ngAfterViewInit()` hook.

Full list of [component lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-sequence).

Answer (score 1):

According to your solution I solved my issue like this:

```
const myHtmlEl = document.getElementsByClassName('my-style').item(0) as HTMLElement;
myHtmltEl.style.display = 'none';
```

but I am sure I have only one item in whole page with class my-style.
otherwise you should loop them with item.length. and apply style to each element.